# php code not being executing in one project xampp

Tags: php, html, xampp

php codes are not parsing, just shows codes as it is
using `xampp`,other projects working fine in same `xampp` server,
no short tags used `<?`.
I tried simple html file also, still showing codes only

Comment: how are you accessing, as `http://localhost` or `file:///`? and the extension for it is what, `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: `http://localhost/`  , i tried both php and html files, all shows the code

Comment: are all services running and properly and well configured? you showed no code also.

Comment: all services running, and other projects also working fine, even simple html file not working

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, for your response, its my fault, i tried `kcfinder`,which generated a `.htaccess` file in project folder that i didn't notice. that contains `php_flag engine Off`